# How to specify a cell range with variables in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to specify a cell range in `openpyxl` using a combination of strings and variables. I understand that a cell range can be generally specified like so; `sheet["A1":"U10"]`.

However, I would like to specify it like this; `sheet["A1":cell]`. Where `cell = "U10"`.

I would then like to use this cell range to apply a font style:

```
fontStyle = Font(name="Calibri", size=12, color=colors.BLACK)
cell = "U" + str(daysAmount)
sheet["A1":cell].font = fontStyle
```

`daysAmount` can always be different in each execution of the program. In this scenario, `daysAmount = 10`

Upon trying this, I am returned with an `AttributeError`, as Python thinks `sheet["A1":cell]` is a tuple:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "businessforecast.py", line 198, in <module>
    textFormatting()
  File "businessforecast.py", line 178, in textFormatting
    sheet["A1":cell].font = fontStyle
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'font'
```

How can I specify a cell range using variables in `openpyxl`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the full traceback, not just the exception being raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "range" of cells is deliberately returned as a tuple or a generator. Use `ws.iter_rows()` or `ws.iter_cols()` to create one programmatically but it will always remain simply a collection of cells. If you want to do something with all of these cells then you will need to do it for every cell in every row or column contained by the range.

Answer (score 1):

According to openpyxl's documentation, you have to reference the cells with a string, like this:

```
sheet ["A1:{}".format(cell)]
```

Comment: This seems to give me the same `AttributeError`, it still thinks it's a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented.
You cannot style ranges.
See openpyxl Issue 414 https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/414/unable-to-style-range-of-cells